# What is Sakura's Chakra Element?

Tags: naruto

Naruto is Wind and Sasuke is Lightning if I'm not wrong. What would Sakura's Chakra element be? Was it mentioned in the series before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can tell, it was never announced officially. While she is shown to have some main skills--medical ninjutsu and strong resistance to genjutsu--her chakra element isn't mentioned.

Everything that I have found ([NarutoHurricane.com](http://www.narutohurricane.com/character-bios/leaf-sakura-haruno.shtml), [Naruto Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sakura_Haruno), etc.) either lists it as a ? or doesn't list it at all. Naruto Wikia lists her chakra transformations (Earth Release, Water Release, Yin Release and Yang Release) but doesn't give her element.

Comment: Her medical skills doesn't rely on any nature chakra's right.

Comment: well when you are good at healing you could say she has a yang affinity but it was never said officially

Answer (score 0):

According to the Naruto Fourth Databook: "Although she doesn't usually use standard ninjutsu, Sakura's natures include Earth, Water, Yin, and Yang Release."