# What is Tsunade's chakra element?

Tags: naruto

In the series, she is celebrated as the world's best medical-nin, and is one of Konohagakure's [Legendary Three Ninja](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sannin). What is her chakra element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it was officially announced. It's just like [Sakura's case](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/17205/what-is-sakuras-chakra-element).

From [Naruto Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tsunade), we find that:

> Tsunade's Nature Types consists of Fire,  Lightning, Earth, Water, Yin <sup>(anime only)</sup> and Yang Release.

Comment: You can of course just use RAW chakra as well (rasengan anyone?) which is what the enhanced punches were, compressed chakra that is precisely released on impact, though Medical ninjutsu is probably Yang type.

http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Chakra_Enhanced_Strength